# Componente de data no padrão americano no Angular

Tags: html, angular

Tenho um DatePicker em meu formulário que digitando a data de forma manual, o componente está esperando que uma data esteja no formato americano e acaba ficando com erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecionando a data pelo próprio componente, funciona normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código do componente no HTML, estou utilizando Angular (7.2.3):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="20">
  <mat-label>Data inicial</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerInicial" [(ngModel)]="startDate">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerInicial">
      <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickerInicial></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar em seu modulo o seguinte provider:

```
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'pt-BR'},
```

Se isso não funcionar tenta pesquisar na documentação por date-picke provide formats e colocar o formato (mascara de data) no padrão brasileiro